# Filter replaces boolean with markup

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm ng-repeat a model to create a table. The model contacts multiple objects that hold boolean values and I want to be able to perform some filter or logic to print markup (a span) instead of the boolean (true, false).

If true, print out a span tag
If false, print nothing.

How would I go about this, a custom filter? or some logic further up the chain instead of at template level.

```
$scope.results = [
            {'date' : '08/02/2014', 'resort' : 'La Plagne', 'sleeps' : '8-9', 'chalet' : 'Arnica', 'offer1' : true, 'offer2' : false, 'offer3' : false, 'offer4' : true, 'offer5' : false, 'offer6' : false, 'offer7' : false, 'pricewas' : '639', 'pricenow' : '249'},
            {'date' : '08/02/2014', 'resort' : 'La Plagne', 'sleeps' : '8-9', 'chalet' : 'Grange', 'offer1' : false, 'offer2' : false, 'offer3' : false, 'offer4' : true, 'offer5' : false, 'offer6' : false, 'offer7' : false, 'pricewas' : '639', 'pricenow' : '249'},
            {'date' : '09/02/2014', 'resort' : 'Tignes', 'sleeps' : '12-14', 'chalet' : 'Chartreux', 'offer1' : false, 'offer2' : false, 'offer3' : false, 'offer4' : false, 'offer5' : false, 'offer6' : false, 'offer7' : false, 'pricewas' : '549', 'pricenow' : '366'},
            {'date' : '15/02/2014', 'resort' : 'La Plagne', 'sleeps' : '8-9', 'chalet' : 'Arnica', 'offer1' : false, 'offer2' : false, 'offer3' : false, 'offer4' : true, 'offer5' : false, 'offer6' : false, 'offer7' : false, 'pricewas' : '639', 'pricenow' : '249'},
            {'date' : '08/02/2014', 'resort' : 'La Plagne', 'sleeps' : '10-13', 'chalet' : 'Renard', 'offer1' : true, 'offer2' : false, 'offer3' : false, 'offer4' : false, 'offer5' : false, 'offer6' : false, 'offer7' : true, 'pricewas' : '1039', 'pricenow' : '699'},
        ];
```

tempalte

```
<tr ng-repeat="result in results">
  <td>
    {{ result.date | date:'medium' }}
  </td>
  <td>
    {{ result.resort }}
  </td>
  <td>
    {{ result.chalet }}
  </td>
  <td>
    {{ result.sleeps }}
  </td>
  <td>
    {{ result.offer1 }}
  </td>
  <td>
    {{ result.offer2 }}
  </td>
  <td>
    {{ result.offer3 }}
  </td>
  <td>
    {{ result.offer4 }}
  </td>
  <td>
    {{ result.offer5 }}
  </td>
  <td>
    {{ result.offer6 }}
  </td>
  <td>
    {{ result.offer7 }}
  </td>
  <td>
    {{ result.pricewas | currency:'£'}}
  </td>
  <td>
    {{ result .pricenow | currency:'£'}}
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: In the official angular tuorial, there's a similar example : [Step 09 - Filters](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09)

Comment: Cheers, Will be going through that entire tutorial set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out the official angular tutorial at [Step 09 - Filters](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09).

More info about how to [create custom filters](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/docs/guide/filter) ;)